# CCSprites in NSMutableArray does not reappear after scene change

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, ccsprite

I am making a game and i am putting CCSprites in a NSMutableArray.

When i start the game for the first time the sprites are appearing on screen, everything seems to work fine.
But when i change to another scene and come back, none of the sprites are visible on screen.
Here below is the code to initialize the Sprites.

```
-(void spritesInit)
    gpsUsersSpritesArray        = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (int i = 0 ; i < [userArray count] ; i++){
      playerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"greenspot.png"];
      playerSprite.position = ccp( winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
      [self addChild:playerSprite z:5];
      [gpsUsersSpritesArray addObject:playerSprite];
      [playerSprite release];
   }
}
```

The above method is run every time the scene is called.

I run the action below on the sprites, that works also fine the first time, but again not when i leave and return to the scene. The sprites seems to be loaded and the code itterates through the NSMutableArray in question without a crash, and this leaves me puzzled.

```
for (CCSprite *userspot in gpsUsersSpritesArray){
   id fadein  = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.05 opacity:255];
   id fadeout = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:dotFadeTime opacity:30];
   id seq2 = [CCSequence actions:fadein, fadeout,nil ];
   [userspot runAction:seq2];
}
```

I have tried to retain the NSMutableArray, but that dit not help either.
Also i have tried to force the sprites to be visible and make sure the opacity of the sprites is set to 255, but still no luck.

I may have overlooked something, but i do not think so.

Who helps me out?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be releasing your sprite. I would think that would cause a crash but it could account for your issue.

When you create a sprite using something like:

```
CCSprite* mysprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"whatever.png"];
```

You NEVER should be releasing that. When coding in Objective-C the rule to remember when not using ARC is that you release objects that you alloc/init, new, retain, and copy yourself. You don't do that in your example code. Inside that method it calls autorelease, making your release invalid. The same with adding objects to containers. Those containers take care of themselves and you should not be releasing or doing anything to the retain count outside of those containers on their behalf if you are using convenience methods that call autorelease, like you are in this case. That is invalid. It would be fine if you were using, for example, alloc/init rather than the spriteWithFile method.

Comment: If i understand you correctly:
because i have used the spriteWithFile method the Sprites will be released when exiting the scene?
Or do you mean no to release the sprite after adding it to the NSMutableArray?

Comment: Both. The method you are specifically calling will autorelease the sprite. When it is added to the layer the layer retains it. Also the layer will release it when the time comes so you don't have to worry about that. The same is true with the container. Think about it like this, when you call that method the sprite is alloc/init and it is set as autorelease. Therefore the init will be released without you needing to do anything further. If you called retain on the sprite then you would have the responsibility to call release to properly drop the retain count.

Comment: In other words every instance where the retain count is increased already has a matching release to decrease it. By you calling release you are throwing things off and the retain count will reach 0 before it should have, which will cause your sprite to be released before it should have been. You only release if you have called retain, alloc/init, new, or copy. If you don't specifically increase the retain count, you should never be decreasing it. The main purpose to methods designed in that way is to make the whole alloc/init/autorelease sequence clean and pretty.

Comment: The thing to remember is that unless you've called retain, alloc/init, new, or copy yourself, you have not created a situation where you need to call release. If you change that line to *mysprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile@"whatever.png"]* then your release would be required. spriteWithFile already took care of that need for you by calling *autorelease* before returning the sprite.

Comment: Thanks Allen,

This is now clear to me.
I allready finished a project and i had no problems with this kind matter. I guess i was lucky there.

So, in what way could i solve this problem to have my sprites on screen again after leaving the scene and comming back to it?

Thank you for your time to explain this (probably) simple object C matter to a guy like me.

Comment: Depending on what you mean, you don't have to do anything different really. If you have a scene and you setup everything you need for that scene in, let's say for example, *onEnter* then every time you go to that scene everything should be setup and working whether it was the first time or the 100th. If these objects are moving and changing during the scene, and you want to be able to return to the scene and start them off at the same state they were at before, then that goes towards the topic of game state management. But...

Comment: ...But in a simple application you could just store the relevant information in a file and load that file the next time you load the scene. Assuming that is what you mean. If you mean simply to show a scene, go to another scene, and show the other scene again, then it should work simply by setting up your scene in either init or onEnter. When you transition to a new scene using *CCDirector's replaceScene*, it shouldn't matter if this was the first or 100th time the scene was shown. It should *just work*. How are you transitioning and where are you calling the code to setup your scene?

Comment: Hi Allen S,

I went back to my earlier project to see what i did different, and together with you last few tips the problem is soved.
Just when you mentioned the init method i had an idea where the problem persist. What i did wrong (i did not know that earlier) that i allocated the NSMutableArrays somewhere else in the code than in the init method. I have moved a testarray with sprites to the init method and whola, the sprites are diplayed every time.

No i have to solve the other sprites Array because the amount of sprites ar fetched from a webserver, i could not do that in the init, could i?

Comment: Good to know. Please accept my answer :). As for the web server thing you can kick off the requests there (but I'd do it in onEnter) and display a loading screen, which could just be a layer covering the screen, in the meanwhile. You can build the scene behind the loading layer and, once all of the request have completed (for better or worst), you can remove the loading screen (layer). If downloading all assets are required, you can display an error if one of them fails and possibly just show an error message as a layer. That is just a simple example to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also be sure to save the files in the documents directory. Also before doing a request to the web server make sure the files were not already downloaded. Unless the files could change and would require re-downloading, in which case you could connect to your web service for some meta data, like a checksum of all required files, and compare that each asset's meta data with what was previously downloaded to see if you need to download that asset again.

Comment: Hi Allen S, last question:

How do i accept your answer, should i click on somewhere at SO Site ?

Comment: There should be an option to accept the answer. Try clicking the up arrow by my answer. That might do it. I forget off the top.

Comment: there is one last thing to tell. I found the solution, i loaded the webdata before i started the scene, so there is no loading screen needed. 

I am not allowed to thank you on the SO site, but what the heck, thank you for you insights.